# Serve cordova.js remotely in PhoneGap 3.x

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, gruntjs

With PhoneGap **`2.x`** I was able to quickly develop apps by making them pull down new assets from my server on `change` rather than re-deploying to the device every time.

I could include `cordova.js` and send it with the other assets and it worked great.

My actual PhoneGap apps were just a shell with **`window.location = "my/dev/server"`** until I needed to distribute them at which point I would pack the assets locally.

I can't seem to do this with **`3.x`**. :(

I can view the needed `cordova.js` but it **"requires"** a bunch of other assets. Maybe something that is packed with a grunt process?

How exactly are these assets (cordova.js + require tree) packed? And how can bundle them into one file for serving remotely in development environment? `<- an answer to these questions gets the bounty`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you on 3.x, but it is definitely possible to re-build the JS file and serve it.

> How exactly are these assets (cordova.js + require tree) packed?

Before they are packed together, they are all laid out in different modules (common, exec, util, platform-specific implementations, etc) and then there is a grunt script that packs everything together.

> And how can bundle them into one file for serving remotely in development environment?

If all you want to do is get the new version of the cordova.js, you should be able to compact everything yourself by downloading the JS source and running the grunt script yourself.

The source is available here: 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-js

It is required that you have node.js, npm, and grunt installed, but if you don't, instructions are in the readme.

Download the source, then run

```
grunt
```

in the root directory, and you should find a 'cordova.ios.js' in the 'pkg' directory, along with the same files for other platforms. That should be the 'cordova.js' that you are looking for.

I think this should help you out, but if not, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful. Do I need to do anything special if I am using plugins? Do they change anything about how the file is packed?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about JS plugins, the script is looking for a file `cordova_plugins.js` in the same directory as `cordova.js`. It does this in the `lib/common/pluginloader.js` that is called on initialization (in `lib/common/init.js`). Unfortunately, that means that you won't be able to pack them together into one file. If you wanted to, you could probably modify the `pluginloader.js` to read the script internally if you wanted to, but it might be easier just to keep them separate.

Comment: If you do go and modify `lib/common/pluginloader.js`, you will have to rebuild the `cordova.ios.js` again by running `grunt`

Comment: What's the best way to check if the `cordova.js` was loaded correctly? My app calls `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo` and it works fine but when I start serving `cordova.js` remotely it stops working. It also doesn't produce any error output so I'm not sure if it's the `cordova.js` file or something else.

Comment: Hmm, well I just got it working by doing the following: 1. create a new project with the CLI interface 2. add the plugin through the CLI 3. change the app-side index.html to do `window.location = "my/dev/server/www/";` 4. Copy the entire `www` folder to my dev server 5. Add the capture logic to my dev-side code; It worked just fine. You will need the `cordova_plugins.js` as well as the `plugins` directory, with all the plugins inside. I don't think there will be a way to compress it into one file.

Comment: Are you upgrading from 2.x, but not yet using the CLI to add plugins and manage the project? If, not I would suggest taking some time to upgrade your project, and hopefully things will run smoother then: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_ios_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20iOS

Comment: This is a new project. I'm pretty sure that it's related to copying over the plugin resources correctly at this point.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure what that is. I copied the entire www folder over, and I'm pretty sure it wouldn't work if you didn't have the plugins server-side.

Comment: yeah my server is set up to pack assets so they need to be organized then a little differently then copying over the directory... need to figure out how exactly these plugin files connect to cordova.js

Comment: I parsed through it and figured out how they called one another. All working now remotely, hooray! Thanks cjwirth

Comment: No kidding! What did you end up doing, move everything into one file, and have the pluginloader load the files differently?

Comment: It was an issue with how things were getting packed and how `cordova.js` injects the plugin script. I ended up just serving them outside of my servers js libs asset flow, similar to how you served them in your description.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know  if that will help you, but here is my understanding of the cordova 3.X :

- You have your cordova.js in your /www folder
- You add your plugins via the CLI (example : cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media )
- There is a folder created in your platforms/[platform]/www/plugins with the javascript plugins needed.
- There is also a 'cordova_plugins.js' in the /www folder
- In cordova.js, at line 1321 ( may depend of your 3.x version) you'll see a function called "injectPluginScript" , and in this function, it injects the contents of 'cordova_plugins.js', which imports the plugins needed in /www/plugins

So I think it might work if you import cordova.js, cordova_plugins.js, and the plugins folder.

Comment: Right, I need to write a script that bundles all of these files into `cordova_bundled.js` then serve that. Do they use grunt to do this or maybe browserify? I've never used grunt.

Comment: I don't know what they use, but you can concatenate JS files via Grunt, and the concat plugin (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat).
You can specify a whole folder to concat to a single file.
Then you can use the uglify task ( https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify ) to minify your file to a .min.js file.

Grunt is easy to learn, I think there are good ressources on their website. If you have problems tell me and I will help with code.

Comment: So, can I define `cordova.js` as an entry file in grunt and it will navigate the require tree and pack everything correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still interested I created a script that packages all needed cordova files for Cordova 3.X, including plugins in one file, that you can serve from your server side.
Only tested in cordove 3.4.

It supports minifying and adding and md5 signature.

https://github.com/borisnieuwenhuis/cordovapackageplugins

Answer (score 0):

Check out Cordova Loader it compiles the assets and servers them: https://github.com/andrewreedy/cordova-loader

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to pack cordova.js **including plugins** into one platform JS file and make it work. Now its possible to upgrade from 2.9 to 3.x, 4.x by just replacing the original cordova.js from 2.9.1 (and upgrading the native part of course). Hope this solves the problem. I am puzzled why cordova does not provide this, but instead relies on dynamically including these files.

Hope this is useful, and saves others the 2 days I spent figuring it out.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo rm -r CordovaPseudoProject
rm -r CordovaPseudoProject
cordova create CordovaPseudoProject com.pseudo.CordovaPseudoProject CordovaPseudoProject
cd CordovaPseudoProject/
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-orientation
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
cordova prepare

# concat all plugin files into a single file
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
cd platforms/ios/www

## extract plugin files
grep '"file":' cordova_plugins.js | sed 's/.* "//g' | sed 's/",//g' > tmp_junk_tmpq
cat cordova_plugins.js > cat_plugins.js
for j in `cat tmp_junk_tmpq` ; do
    echo "cat $j >>cat_plugins.js"
    cat $j >> cat_plugins.js
done
rm tmp_junk_tmpq

# overwrite cordova_plugins.js with concatenated version
#echo cp cat_plugins.js cordova_plugins.js
#cp cat_plugins.js cordova_plugins.js

echo cat cordova.js cat_plugins.js to cordova_platform_complete.js
cat cordova.js cat_plugins.js > cordova_platform_complete.js

cd $CUR_WD
echo "CREATED CordovaPseudoProject/platforms/ios/www/cordova_platform_complete.js"
```